# Slight trouble converting tables to div's/CSS

Tags: css

I'm in the process of taking out tables from an entire site, and switching them to CSS Div's.

Here's the link of the first one I'm trying:
http://www.torelloengineers.com/legal_investigations.html

The problem is the content to the right is being put below the picture to the left, rather than being right next to it.

I created this in my CSS file: a container, row, and left, right, and middle for the table cells.  I couldn't paste it exactly here because the text box wasn't allowing formatted code.

```
<div id="row">
    <div id="left">
        <h4><img src="picts/torello-safety-design.jpg" width="400" height="301"></h4>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        <h4>Lacking Good Safety Design - Missing Guardrail.  Plainville, CT</h4>
        <p>While returning to her parked vehicle after using an ATM.... </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I "dived" the content I wanted as left and right on the main page to where I wanted it, but the right content won't line up with the left.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see a CSS file that had the IDs #left and #right in it. Are the ids #left and #right floated left and/or right?

```
#left {
    float: left;
}
#right {
    float: right;
}
```

You might want to change those to classes too, just to make it easier to reuse them. :)

Comment: Hi Tim:  Here is the style sheet.  The coding for the CSS positioning is at the bottom:        http://www.torelloengineers.com/colors/torellostyle.css

Comment: Sorry. i saw that file and searched for .left by mistake. not enough caffeine today... :P I'd probably remove the table cells and go to floated divs, or absolute position.

Answer (score 0):

Try `position:absolute` or `position:relative`

Answer (score 0):

`<div id="right">` is formatted as a table cell. Check the vertical alignment for the text - `vertical-align:baseline`. Personally I would remove the table cell formatting and use a regular div.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
#left {width: 50%; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;}
#right {width: 50%; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;}
```

Adjust widths to your liking. Floats allow content to wrap around them, so they're an option as well.

While you're in there, change

"Here's a few examples of past work we have done for attorney's:"

to

"Here're a few examples of past work we have done for attorneys:"